# How to evaluate the Date in MVEL

Tags: java, datetime, mvel

I need to evaluate the criteria string using the MVEL. I can able to compare all the primitive value. I am facing the problem while comparing the Date. The MVEL supports the default date format 'dd-MMM-yyyy' only.But I need to compare the util date against string Date using MVEL. The following code through the exception

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private Date joiningDate;

    public Date getJoiningDate() {
        return joiningDate;
    }
    public void setJoiningDate(Date joiningDate) {
        this.joiningDate = joiningDate;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Raja");
        person.setAge(30);
        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        //24-August -2016
        calendar.set(2016, 7, 24);
        Date joiningDate = calendar.getTime();
        person.setJoiningDate(joiningDate);
        // all the constant fetched from DB
        String criteria = "name == 'Raja' && age == 30 && joiningDate <=\"24-Aug-2016\"";
        System.out.println("Is Criteria match : "+isCriteriaMatch(criteria, person));
    }

    private static boolean isCriteriaMatch(String criteria, Object object) {
        boolean istrue = false;
        if (criteria != null && !criteria.isEmpty()) {
            istrue = MVEL.evalToBoolean(criteria, object);
        }
        return istrue;
    }

    private static String formatDate(Date date){
        System.out.println("Date : "+date);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        return "\"".concat(sdf.format(date)).concat("\"");
        //return sdf.format(date);
    }
}
```

The Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" [Error: failed to subEval expression]
[Near : {... name == 'Raja' && age == 30 && joiningDate <="24-Aug-2016" ....}]
                                                          ^
[Line: 1, Column: 46]
    at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.reduce(AbstractParser.java:2627)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.arithmeticFunctionReduction(AbstractParser.java:2526)
    at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parseAndExecuteInterpreted(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:147)
    at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parse(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:47)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.eval(MVEL.java:270)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.evalToBoolean(MVEL.java:623)
    at com.scb.mvel.App.isCriteriaMatch(App.java:27)
    at com.scb.mvel.App.main(App.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: uncomparable values <<Wed Aug 24 12:52:37 IST 2016>> and <<24-Aug-2016>>
    at org.mvel2.math.MathProcessor.doOperationNonNumeric(MathProcessor.java:321)
    at org.mvel2.math.MathProcessor._doOperations(MathProcessor.java:234)
    at org.mvel2.math.MathProcessor.doOperations(MathProcessor.java:79)
    at org.mvel2.math.MathProcessor.doOperations(MathProcessor.java:48)
    at org.mvel2.util.ExecutionStack.op(ExecutionStack.java:178)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.reduce(AbstractParser.java:2567)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
    at java.util.Date.compareTo(Date.java:129)
    at org.mvel2.math.MathProcessor.doOperationNonNumeric(MathProcessor.java:318)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Are you sure day-month-year matches your culture settings?

Comment: It supports the "dd-MMM-yyyy" format with enclosed double quote

Comment: @sathyendrana i ran your code and called function `formatDate`, made `joiningDate` as `string property`, worked well, what is the issue then. MVEL supports the format `dd-MMM-yyyy`

Comment: Its support the only dd-MMM-yyyy format only. If I need to compare the other format for ex yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss then it throws error